# How is the time complexity of these simple loops calculated?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I understand how:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

This time complexity is `O(n)`.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        for (k=0; k<n; k++)
```

this is `O(n^3)` right?

```
i=1
do
    //......
    i++
while (i*2 <n)
```

Is this `O(n)`? Or is it exactly `O(n/2)`?

Comment: 1/2 is a constant. O(n/2) = O(n).

Answer (score 1):

`O(n/2)` *is* `O(n)` only with a constant coefficient of 1/2. The coefficient can be 10 billion, it would still be `O(n)`, and not e.g. `O(n^(1.0001))` which is a different complexity class.

Answer (score 1):

The first one of *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*, you're right.

Your second algorithm is *O(n/2)* = *O(Cn)* = *O(n)*. *1/2* is a constant so we can safety discard it.

Answer (score 1):

The first one complexity O(n^3), correct.
The second one, O(cn), c constant. No matter how huge c is, according to the definition of big-O, the complexity is still O(n).

However, O-notation is considered harmful. See [here](http://jng.imagine27.com/index.php/2013-02-10-121226_analytic-combinatorics-is-better-o-nation-considered-harmful.html).

Answer (score 0):

This fragment of code:

```
i=1
do
    //......
    i++
while (i*2 < n);
```

is equivalent to that one:

```
for ( i = 1; i < n / 2 ; ++ i );
```

Superficially, this is `O(n)`.